# "Couldn't match type `Maybe' with `IO' Expected type: IO String Actual type: Maybe String" In Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

I am trying to wrap my head around Monads, and feel that if I could get an explaination to why this doesn't compile, I'd have a better understanding.

```
module Main where
import Data.Maybe
import System.Environment

myFunc :: String-> Maybe String
myFunc x = Just x

main :: IO ()
main = myFunc "yo" >>= putStrLn
```

The error I get is

```
blah.hs:9:10:
    Couldn't match type `Maybe' with `IO'
    Expected type: IO String
      Actual type: Maybe String
    In the return type of a call of `myFunc'
    In the first argument of `(>>=)', namely `myFunc "yo"'
    In the expression: myFunc "yo" >>= putStrLn
```

I realize that the issue is that I'm trying to match a `Maybe` with an `IO`, but I'm not entire sure how to cast my Maybe'd variable into an IO. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct in realizing that you are trying to match a `Maybe` with an `IO`. For the bind (`>>=`) operator to typecheck, both the Monad should be the same. One way to solve this problem would be to wrap the `Maybe` in an `IO` monad using `return`:

```
return (myFunc "yo") >>= putStrLn . show
```

Or more simply:

```
return (myFunc "yo") >>= print
```

---

That being said, you don't need all the fancy monad operators here. This should simply work:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print . myFunc $ "yo"
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that print could take a `Maybe String` as an argument.

Comment: @Tombert `print` is defined as `putStrLn . show`. So it can take any type which has an instance of `Show` defined!

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the console doesn't output Just "yo" and instead outputs "yo"?

Comment: @Tombert Then what do you want to print for `Nothing` ?

Comment: in this case, I'd probably want to print an empty string or something, but it looks like jcast covered my confusion.

Comment: @Tombert One way would be to do like this for what you want: `main = print $ maybe "" id (myFunc "yo")`. That will print `yo` instead of `Just "yo"`

Answer (score 3):

Casting `Maybe String` to `IO` is the same as turning a `Maybe String` to anything else: you need to pick a value to map `Nothing` to, and a value to map each `Just x` to.  Since you want to map to `IO String`, I assume you want to map `Nothing` to an exception and `Just x` to `return x`:

```
import Control.Exception

data NoString = NoString deriving (Typeable, Show)
instance Exception NoString

maybeToIO :: Maybe String -> IO String
maybeToIO Nothing = throwIO NoString
maybeToIO (Just x) = return x

main = maybeToIO (myFunc "yo") >>= putStrLn
```

However, I suspect that, in a real application, you would want to map `Nothing` onto defined behavior; maybe printing nothing, for example:

```
main = case myFunc "yo" of
    Nothing -> return ()
    Just x -> putStrLn x
```

Basically, don't get too hung up on the fact that `Maybe` and `IO` are both monads; the monad operations are just ways of *making* values of those types; once you've got your `Maybe` values, you still need to process them as ordinary data structures (although Haskell does have awesome ways of doing that:

```
main = maybe (return ()) putStrLn $ myFun "yo"
```

for example).